# What branch of mathematics describes fluid motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, soft-question, terminology, navier-stokes

I was wondering if there is a specific branch of mathematics that is used to describe fluid motion?  I know that calculus is used to describe rates of change in fluid motion (i.e. how fast a container will fill up or empty).  But what other phenomena of fluid motion can we explain?  Some of the other things I can think of are fluid pressure and the way fluids will over a surface or container.  What else am I missing?

Comment: Fluid dynamics, hydrodynamics, vortices, hurricanes, plenty more. The math is like everything else lots of things, starting from differential equations.

Comment: @BobBee are there any differences between fluid dynamics, hydrodynamics and aerodynamics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Navier-Stokes equations and the diffusion equation are the main equations in fluid dynamics. They are partial differential equations derived from the branch of math called vector calculus.